# Is it okay to catch java.util.zip.ZipError?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, zip

Why would `java.util.zip.ZipError` be thrown, and is it okay to catch it?

The javadoc says that it means that an unrecoverable error has occurred - but what would such an error be? I have heard that it can occur from bad zip files.

EDIT:

Looking at the java.util.zip sources shows that it is thrown when an attempt is made to access an element in the file that does not exist, but the `java.util.zip.ZipFile` class's internal count indicates that the element should exist. This can occur if another thread tried to close the file after the `ensureOpen` method checked for this, or if something went wrong in the native methods called by `java.util.zip.ZipFile`. This looks like it could occur if the file was changed while the Java application had it open. I don't really understand the entirity of the codebase involved though (it is big!).

Comment: Why wouldn't you catch it?

Comment: @redFIVE As it is an error and not an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that JDK issue [JDK-4615343](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4615343) prompted the creation of `ZipError` in Java 6.  [A comment on the issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4615343?focusedCommentId=12253601&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-12253601) sheds some light on the existence of `ZipError`:

> Instead of throwing an InternalError, the zip file implementation now
>   throws java.util.zip.ZipError.
>
> The new exception is controversial and extends InternalError. In
>   general, this not recommended pratice but was needed for
>   compatibility. Existing programs may have worked around this problem
>   by catching InternalError. Such programs will continue to work but we
>   recommend that all clients are updated to catch java.util.zip.ZipError
>   instead.

This indicates that that `ZipError` is a known bad design that exists solely for backwards compatibility reasons.

Looking at the Java 8 source code likewise confirms that `ZipError` is only thrown by the `ZipFile` iteration methods: [entries()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries--) and [stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#stream--).

A look at the Java 9 source code reveals that Java 9  takes it a step further, and no longer throws `ZipError` at all.

As to why it would be thrown, the [TestZipError.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/00cd9dc3c2b5/test/java/util/zip/TestZipError.java) source code in OpenJDK 8 shows one such scenario.  A `ZipError` will be thrown in Microsoft Windows if a `ZipFile` object is created, followed by deleting the zip file in the filesystem and creating it with different entries, then iterating through the `ZipFile`'s contents.

These details provide strong evidence that — unlike most `Error`s — it is in fact reasonable to catch a thrown `ZipError` and handle it as though it were a normal non-`Error` exception.  Though if the code will only be running on Java 9+ one may not want to bother with the check at all, as it would be superfluous code for an impossible situation.

Comment: Guess what, this has been silently changed in JDK 9, but not backported. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8037394 and http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/7af354d25024. Well done, Oracle!

Comment: @Michael-O That's a great find. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`ZipError` indicates a low-level JVM error and, although you may catch it just like any other exception, there is a chance that the whole JVM is at that moment in such a state that it shouldn't continue to run. Note that there is a separate `ZipException` for more regular sort of errors, like corrupt files, I/O errors etc.